# My app crashes on lg devices when I am clicking the ad

Tags: android, crash, admob

My app crashes on LG devices when I am clicking the ad (from admob)!. What's the problem?

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class <unknown> at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)     at     
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)  at
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)    at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)    at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)    at 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3090)  at 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3150)    at 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1737)    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2683)   at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)   at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)  at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1204)    at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4952)   at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)    at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)    at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)     at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)     ... 21 more 
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=-1     at 
android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3638)    at 
android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:427)   at 
android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)   at 
android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)   ... 24 more
```

..................................................................................................

Comment: Add the code where the error is pointing?

Answer (score 1):

It's issue with [LG Optimus L9 P760](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_optimus_l9_p760-4955.php) device. It occurs only on version 4.1.2, I see it every now and then in my apps. If your application is available on any store and it's serious problem to you remember that you can always disable this device from supported devices.

I don't think there's anything to worry about. In my case the layout isn't complicated so the solution proposed by @Kishan with flattening view hierarchy will not work. It's just manufacturer fault.

Answer (score -1):

This same error was there in my previous application. its because of the internal memory stack of the device (Some thing like RAM) is full. so for overcoming this error see the hierarchy of layout. and see the time of inflating in the hierarchy view if android eclipse IDE. and decrease the hierarchy of the layout. i have solved my issue with this. so you can check this if you can solve by the same solution.

Hope you can understand this solution.